# How can I display lots of rows of information from a database in my drupal module?

Tags: database, 7

In the example_page I believe it shows something like this:

```
function foo() {
    return array('#markup' => t('bar'));
}
```

And the function foo would be used for a page callback in the menu hook to create a page. However, In my module I plan on using a db_query to access a database table and with it display many rows of data.

Is there a better way to do this than stuffing all of my output into #markup? It could be done with lots of concatenation, but it would be rather messy and it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to build an HTML table then the [`theme_table()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) function will help a lot. See the docs page for full details but this is a basic example:

```
function MYMODULE_page_callback() {
  // Header for the table
  $header = array('id', 'name');

  // Get your data
  $data = db_query('SELECT id, name FROM {my_table}')->fetchAllKeyed();

  // Loop through the data and add rows to the table
  $rows = array();
  foreach ($data as $id => $name) {
    $rows[] = array(
      $id,
      $name
    );
  }

  // Return the themed table
  return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

  // You could also use:
  return array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much again. Sorry for the simple questions, I really know PHP,SQL, & HTML, but learning how to program for drupal almost feels like another language lol.

Comment: Don't mention it :) Drupal is notorious for having a steep learning curve but trust me it's worth it if you persevere!